# I want to print the Head's name according to the employees name

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print the Head of Abhishek that is Sumita Nath dynamically, but the head is not displayed. Why is it so?
I have tried many times with different way but the output is not displayed. This is my data:

```
   $employee = array
(
0=>
    array("employee_id"=>1, "firstName"=>"Zahir", "lastName"=>"Alam", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
1=>
    array("employee_id"=>2, "firstName"=>"Amith", "lastName"=>"Manniken", "Age"=>25, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Developer", "Department"=>"Tech"
        ,"Head"=>
            array("Id"=>3 , "Name"=>"Sourasis Roy")
    )
,
2=>
    array("employee_id"=>3, "firstName"=>"Sourasis", "lastName"=>"Roy", "Age"=>28, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"CTO")
,
3=>
    array("employee_id"=>4, "firstName"=>"Aditya", "lastName"=>"Mishra", "Age"=>29, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Department"=>"Tech", "Role"=>"CEO")
,
4=>
    array("employee_id"=>5, "firstName"=>"Priti", "lastName"=>"Lata", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HR")
,
5=>
    array("employee_id"=>6, "firstName"=>"Sumita", "lastName"=>"Nath", "Age"=>24, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA Head", "Department"=>"Crm")
,
6=>
    array("employee_id"=>7, "firstName"=>"Tarini", "lastName"=>"Khanna", "Age"=>22, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"Content Writer")
,
7=>
    array("employee_id"=>8, "firstName"=>"Abhisek", "lastName"=>"Soni", "Age"=>23, "Company"=>"Switchme", "Role"=>"HLA", "Department"=>"Crm","Head"=>array("Id"=>5 , "Name"=>"Sumita Nath")
    )
    );
```

and this is what I have tried:

```
$name="Abhishek";
echo "The Head of ";
echo $name;
echo " is ";
$key = array_search($name, array_column($employee, 'Head','Name'));
//print $employee[7]["Head"echo array_]["Name"];
echo $key;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't search in the `Head` array for the employee name, you need to search the `firstName` column, and then check to see if that employee has a `Head` array, and if so, output the `Name` value from that array:

```
$name="Abhishek";
echo "The Head of $name is ";
$key = array_search($name, array_column($employee, 'firstName'));
if ($key !== false && isset($employee[$key]['Head'], $employee[$key]['Head']['Name'])) {
    echo $employee[$key]['Head']['Name'];
}
else {
    echo "nobody";
}
```

Output:

```
The Head of Abhishek is Sumita Nath
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bTGRt)

Comment: @Clarke you have a misspelling in either your `$employee` array or `$name`, one has `Abhisek` and the other has `Abhishek`, I corrected that in my demo

Comment: Yes i got it too. Thank you for your help